# Find & Replace in 80mb file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

Is there a command line or a  tool in Ubuntu to "Find & Replace" a word in a 80mb file that accours about 150000 times?

I want to replace `http://www.old-domain.com/subfolderA` with `http://www.new-domain.com/subfolderB`

I tried it with gEdit and Atom but both crashed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sed` can do:

```bsh
sed -i.bak '/oldword/s//newword/g' very_big_file
```

This edits the file directly leaving a backup named `very_big_file.bak`. It scans your file for lines containing `oldword` and replaces every occurence with `newword`, which should be much faster than running `s/oldword/newword/g` over *every* line (see [Replace text quickly in very large file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255373/246819)). Quoting [sed1line](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt):

> OPTIMIZING FOR SPEED: If execution speed needs to be increased (due to
>   large input files or slow processors or hard disks), substitution will
>   be executed more quickly if the "find" expression is specified before
>   giving the "s/.../.../" instruction. Thus:
>
> ```bsh
> sed 's/foo/bar/g' filename         # standard replace command   
> sed '/foo/ s/foo/bar/g' filename   # executes more quickly
> sed '/foo/ s//bar/g' filename      # shorthand sed syntax
> ```

If `oldword` and/or `newword` contain slashes you can either escape them with backslash (e.g. `http:\/\/www`) or use a different delimiter, e.g. underscore:

```bsh
sed -i.bak '/oldword/s__newword_g' very_big_file
sed -i.bak '\_oldword_s//newword/g' very_big_file
sed -i.bak '\_oldword_s__newword_g' very_big_file
```

In your exact case I would do:

```bsh
sed -i.bak '\_http://www.old-domain.com/subfolderA_s__http://www.new-domain.com/subfolderB_g' very_big_file
```